# javascript replace url

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone write a javascript code that replace

```
"www.mydomain.com/happy_new_year/yeah-00-14-jj-78-aaa1.html"
```

to

```
"www.mydomain.com/happy_new_year/ohoh-11-22-33-44-aaa1.html"
```

Note that the folder in this case `/happy_new_year/` will stay the same.

But we don't know the exact folder name, could be something else, and sometimes no folder is present, and don't need to change.

Replace every character after that except the last 4 characters before .html

There is a pattern of how many slashes '-' could be useful.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use regular expressions. Learn more at http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression

```
url.replace(/[^\/]*(....\.html)$/,new_name + "$1");
```

The `$` sign tells the match to start from the end of the string, it then captures `.html` and the next four characters in a group, and eventually matches as many characters that are not a `/` as possible. The `$1` in the replacement expands to the captured group.

Comment: but how do i keep the last four characters before .html, and those 4 char can be any combination of numbers and letters